# Windows Makefiles and TEXINPUTS

Tags: windows, makefile, texinputs

under Windows (using make from GnuWin32) i want to set my TEXINPUTS variable in a makefile

My Structure is as follows:

```
./
|-texmf_project/
   |-Package.sty
|-main.tex
|-makefile
```

I want to be able to use Package.sty in my compilation process. The files look like this:
Package.sty contains:

```
\ProvidesClass{Package}[]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
```

main.tex contains:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{Package}
\begin{document}
    Hello World\\
    \red{Hello World}
\end{document}
```

Now i want to set the TEXINPUTS to include what is in ./texmf-project/
Hence my Makefile:

```
edit:
    set TEXINPUTS=./texmf-project//;
    pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode main.tex
    del *.log
    del *.aux
```

However this does not seem to make the location available for compilation.
However if I put the line
 `set TEXINPUTS=./texmf-project//;` directly into the cmd and run make afterwards it works.

I believe I am making a mistake with the set, but I am far from beeing an expert.
Any helps or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Fixed a spelling mistake

Comment: I think this is one for StackOverflow - it's essentially a pure Makefile question (how to set the environment for a Windows program from a Makefile)

Comment: I can transfer for you - you may need to edit once that happens to be clearly on-topic

Comment: Oh, sorry. I already just copied and pasted ist over. Will put an answer here if I get one. Maybe this increases the chance of others with similar problem to find a solution